# Assignment by reference or value when using $this?

Tags: php, object

I'm confused about the following output in this linked list

```
class ListNode{
    public $next = NULL;
    public $data = NULL;
    public function __construct($data){
        $this->data = $data;
    }

}

class LinkedList{
    private $firstNode = NULL;
    private $lastNode = NULL;


    public function insertFirst($data){
        $link = new ListNode($data);
        $link->next = $this->firstNode;
        $this->firstNode = &$link;
        if($this->lastNode == NULL){
            $this->lastNode = &$link;
        }

    }

    public function readList(){
        while($this->firstNode != NULL){
            echo $this->firstNode->data;
            $this->firstNode = $this->firstNode->next;
        }
    }

    public function assessList(){
        $copy = $this->firstNode;
        echo $copy->data;
        echo $this->firstNode->data;
        $copy->data = 'm';
        echo $copy->data;
        echo $this->firstNode->data;        
    }

}

$linkedList = new LinkedList();
$linkedList->insertFirst('c');
$linkedList->insertFirst('b');
$linkedList->insertFirst('a');
//$linkedList->readList();  //output a b c
$linkedList->assessList();  //outputs a a m m
```

I would expect the output to be `a a m a`.  I thought `$copy` is just a copy of the value stored in `$this->firstNode`.

Isn't this line of code `$copy = $this->firstNode` an assignment by value?  I would expect the output to be `a a m m` if it was an assignment by reference `$copy = &$this->firstNode` but not if it was an assignment by value.

Can someone please clarify?

**EDIT (additional example)**

```
public function assessList(){
    $copy = $this->firstNode->data;
    echo $copy. "<br/>";
    echo $this->firstNode->data. "<br/>";
    $copy = 'm';
    echo $copy. "<br/>";
    echo $this->firstNode->data. "<br/>";       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
$copy = $this->firstNode;
```

Is not a copy of the object, it's a copy of the "pointer" to the original object, so when you modify it, you modify the underlying object. You need to use the [`clone`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) keyword to get a true copy:

```
$copy = clone $this->firstNode;
```

From the PHP [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) (emphasis mine):

> When assigning an already created instance of a class to a new
>   variable, the new variable will access the **same instance** as the object
>   that was assigned.

You can see from [this example](http://viper-7.com/dkPTkz) that your code snippet now outputs:

```
aama
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One quick question.  What if it was a property instead of an object  Ex `$copy = $this->firstNode->data`?  Is `$copy` a copy of the pointer to the property or is this an assignment by value?

Comment: What you're looking for there is a deep copy. The standard `clone` is not deep, you'd need to implement your own `__clone()` method to perform a deep copy.

Comment: nick - So you're saying `$copy = $this->firstNode->data` is not actually making a copy?  I wrote some test code (see edit: additional example) and it seems to pass by value

Comment: It's not making a copy. Both `$copy` and `$this->firstNode` point to the same object. If `->data` is an object, it will not be copied with `clone`. Instead, both `$copy->firstNode->value` and `$this->firstNode->value` will point to the same object, unless you implement your own `__clone()` method. If `->value` is not an object, it will be copied. When you use the terms `pass by value` / `pass by reference`, those are not appropriate here, as they are used in the context of calling functions and how their parameters are accepted